# обрезать http:// в url если есть

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В форму передают урл с http:// и без него. Как обрезать его если он есть?

Comment: А зачем вам регулярные выражения. str_ireplace('http://','',$str);

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'http://domain.com/';
$str = preg_replace('!^https?://!i', '', $str); // Удаляем с начала строки http:// и https://
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$cleanUrl = preg_replace('/(http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)/', '', $url, 1, null);
```

Comment: 1. Без символа начала строки такая регулярка может и что то лишнее обрезать. 2. Какой смысл передавать null 5-ый параметр, он ведь и так по дефолту.